# creating time intervals which doesn't exist in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time, intervals

I have -machine error/machine stop- data in detail of plant, workstation, machine, start datetime and end datetime.

I want to create time intervals when the machines run properly with python/pandas

As a result I want to have 24-hour timeline and each interval tagged as working(if no error occured) or not working.

dataframe looks like below for 1 station(total 17), 1 machine type(total 10) and 1 day;

```
Stat.  Mac.   start_date          end_date            start_no   end_no  status
 A     B    2019-01-03 00:00:00  2019-01-03 01:30:00     1         90     pause
 A     B    2019-01-03 09:35:00  2019-01-03 10:20:00    575        620    pause
 A     B    2019-01-03 20:20:00  2019-01-03 20:40:00    1220       1240   pause
 A     B    2019-01-03 21:45:00  2019-01-03 22:45:00    1305       1365   pause
```

Requested dataframe should look like below for same workstation-machine-day pair;

```
    Stat.  Mac.   start_date          end_date            start_no   end_no  status
     A     B    2019-01-03 00:00:00  2019:01:03 00:00:01     0         1      working
     A     B    2019-01-03 00:00:00  2019-01-03 01:30:00     1         90     pause
     A     B    2019-01-03 01:30:00  2019-01-03 09:35:00     90        575    working
     A     B    2019-01-03 09:35:00  2019-01-03 10:20:00    575        620    pause
     A     B    2019-01-03 10:20:00  2019-01-03 20:20:00    620        1220   working
     A     B    2019-01-03 20:20:00  2019-01-03 20:40:00    1220       1240   pause
     A     B    2019-01-03 20:40:00  2019-01-03 21:45:00    1240       1305   working
     A     B    2019-01-03 21:45:00  2019-01-03 22:45:00    1305       1365   pause
     A     B    2019-01-03 22:45:00  2019-01-03 23:59:00    1365       1439   working
```

I uploaded sample dataframe(1000rows-~80kb) in below link;

https://gofile.io/?c=tKA8Qj

how should I approach this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: To get the best results, make sure that both your posted data and the linked file are in the same format (column numbers and names). Also, `start_date` and `end_date` are present in both data sets but have a different meaning. Any solution will have to be tweaked to work for the other data set.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, actually I only posted important columns for clarity, but you're right, I edited the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this problem we have a sequential pattern and we can transform "start_no" and "end_no" columns to the columns of the desired data-frame.
When we take the values like `(start_no0, end_no0, start_no1, end_no1, ...)`, we actually get the biggest part of desired columns of "start_no" and "end_no". And with a simple fix we can get exactly same columns. The same logic can be applied to start_date and end_date, since they represent kind of same things.

Since you have different station and machine values, we can divide our problem into groups by indexed with Stat., Mac., start_date, end_date. In the code I tried to do that by ignoring the time fields in your original data-set in order to get all values in the day. Basically I just grouped the data and iterate each group to create a new data-frame which contains the information you desire.

The code is like following for the case that you shared:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel("sample_2.xlsx")

# transform (start|end)_date as only date without time
data["_sDate"] = data.start_date.apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
data["_eDate"] = data.end_date.apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

# group the data by following columns
grouped = data.groupby(["Station","Machine","_sDate","_eDate"])
# container for storing result of each group
container = []

# iterate the groups
for name, group in grouped:
    # sort them by start_number
    group = group.sort_values("start_number")
    # get (start|end)_numbers into a flatten array
    nums = group[["start_number", "end_number"]].values.flatten()
    # get (start|end)_date into a flatten array
    dates = group[["start_date", "end_date"]].values.flatten()
    ## insert required values to nums and dates
    # we add the first pause time at index 1 to show first working interval
    dates = np.insert(dates, 1 , dates[0] + nums[0]*10**9)
    # we add 0 in the beginning of the array to show first working interval
    nums = np.insert(nums, 0, 0)
    # create df
    nrow = nums.size-1      # decrement, because we add one additional element
    newdf = pd.DataFrame({
        "Station": np.tile(("A"),nrow),
        "Machine": np.tile(("B"),nrow),
        "start_date": dates[:-1],
        "end_date": dates[1:],
        "start_no": nums[:-1],
        "end_no": nums[1:],
        "status": np.tile(["working", "pause"], nrow//2)
    })
    container.append(newdf)

df_final = pd.concat(container)
df_final.index = range(0,df_final.shape[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick, but slow method could be to just loop over all rows and check the current + next row. You only have 1000 rows so this would be just fine for now. This will look something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("sample_2.xlsx")

df['status'] = 'pause'

df = df.sort_values(['Workcenter','Machine','Error_Reason','Class','start_date','start_time', 'end_date','end_time']).reset_index()
new_df = df.copy()

number_rows = len(df)-1
for i in range(number_rows):
    row = df.loc[i]
    next_row = df.loc[i+1]

    new_row = row
    new_row['status'] = 'working'
    new_row['start_date'] = row['end_date']
    new_row['end_date'] = next_row['start_date']
    new_row['start_number'] = row['end_number']
    new_row['end_number'] = next_row['start_number']
    new_df = new_df.append(new_row)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but since there is none if control between rows it only takes next row's information. for example if next row's day is different it should auto complete to 1440(24 hour*60 minutes), but anyway thanks again it is a good start for me

Comment: That's why you first need to sort it. I did that here, but maybe you can sort in a better way. `df = df.sort_values(['Workcenter','Machine','Error_Reason','Class','start_date','start_time', 'end_date','end_time']).reset_index()` I

Comment: yes. but this method doesn't create 0 to start_number and end_number to 1440 rows. It only creates rows between paused rows.
for example for one day there is one entry and start_number is: 250 end_number is 310. I need to create two more rows. first row's start_number:0, end_number:250 - working, last row's start_number : 310 and end number:1440-working